# How to setup Identity Server 4 with MySQL

Tags: .net, identityserver4

I am trying to configure Identity server 4 with backend database as mysql but not able to find any guidance tutorial on official site of Idserver4 to configure.
Is it possible with mysql?

Comment: Are you sure? The site's Quickstart explains [how to use *Entity Framework*](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) which can target any database with an EF provider. Configuring EF to work with MySQL is the same as configuring it to use SQL Server. The only concern is whether there is an EF Core provider for MySQL available or not

Comment: Looks like there is an [EF Core provider for MySQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos getting error Package MySql.Data 6.9.9 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1

Comment: MySql.Data 6.9.9 doesn't support .NET Core. 7.0.1 does. Add the latest MySQL.Data provider first, then add the EF Core provider package.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In startup.cs getting error  UseMySql not available services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Comment: You can refer this link https://youtu.be/X4I0DUw6C84 and here is the detailed article https://www.tutlinks.com/asp-net-core-react-identity-server-4-using-mysql/

Answer (score 5):

Focus on the 8_AspNetIdentity example in the IdentityServer samples.

Add the  MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore nuget package.

As a precaution before you start, run the migrations into Sql Server. We will revisit this.

Begin by changing the connectionString in Appsettings.json

```
        "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;userid=root;pwd=rootpassword;persistsecurityinfo=True;port=3306;database=AspIdUsers;sslmode=none;AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=true;"
```

Note that your database password is here in plain text, so if this file is visible to a wider audience, use user secrets to supply it.

The Context definition will need some work because MySql persists booleans as integers ant that will lead to coercion exceptions if they are not mapped. Add the following to the OnModelCreating method of ApplicationDbContext:

```
            // Conversions required for "No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int16' and 'System.Boolean'."
            builder
        .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .Property(u => u.EmailConfirmed).HasConversion<Int16>()
        ;

            builder
        .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .Property(u => u.LockoutEnabled).HasConversion<Int16>()
        ;

            builder
          .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
          .Property(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasConversion<Int16>()
          ;

            builder
          .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
          .Property(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasConversion<Int16>()
          ;

            builder
          .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
          .Property(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled).HasConversion<Int16>()
          ;
            builder
           .Entity<ApplicationUser>()
           .Property(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasConversion<Int16>()
           ;
```

Tell Startup.cs to use MySql rather than Sql Server:

```
      services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySQL(connectionString));
```

Change the migration modules 20180109192453_CreateIdentitySchema.Designer and ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot to set a max lenght on the key fields of AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserTokens (which has a three part key so use length 200).

```
            modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin<string>", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<string>("LoginProvider")
                     .HasMaxLength(256);

                    b.Property<string>("ProviderKey")
                     .HasMaxLength(256);

                    b.Property<string>("ProviderDisplayName");

                    b.Property<string>("UserId")
                     .HasMaxLength(256)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasKey("LoginProvider", "ProviderKey");

                    b.HasIndex("UserId");

                    b.ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
                });
```

This list may not be complete so if you encounter a migration error telling you that your key exceeds the 3072 limit, note the table and use this example to reduce its length as required.

If manipulating the migration is proving impossible, export the create statements from SqlServer and handcraft their MySql equivalent.

After you have successfully created the database, you will need to use MySql Workbency to set the AutoIncrement on the Id Column of AspNetUserClaims.

Then you should be good to go.

If you opt for the Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage, things get a lot more complicated. You do not get access to the ConfigurationDbContext and PersistedGrantDbContext. They are managed through the Indentity Server 4 nuget packages so you will need to inject your own versions in order to resolve the coercion issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
services.AddDbContext<yourDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(yourConnectionName, mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.CommandTimeout(timeout)));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.